# Is there any performance difference between UNIQUE INDEX and INDEX with the same cardinality on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a table that has `id` and `created_at`.

```
Column     | Non Unique | Cardinality
-------------------------------------
id         | 0          | 1000
created_at | 1          | 1000
```

`id` is `unique`, and `created_at` is `non unique`.

I want to know if there's any performance improvement if I convert the `created_at` index from `non unique` to `unique`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no difference for read operations, once written the entries in the index will be the same.

In theory there is a slight difference in update performance as the engine needs to enforce uniqueness in a unique index, but in reality this is one going to be at most a few CPU cycles per row difference so will be unnoticeable.

Only create a unique index for values that you know should be unique. It is quite conceivable that two items could be created at the same time (or at least within the granularity of the data type you are using for that column).

Comment: Approaching it from a purely empirical perspective in Postgres, I noticed that when I (accidentally) created an index on the columns that were already my primary key (same columns, same order), Postgres actually gave a slightly higher cost without the extra index (through `EXPLAIN`). Of course, that is just one database, plus the cost difference was less than a percent.

Answer (score 5):

First, I must emphasize that you should use `UNIQUE` when you need the uniqueness check, *not* for performance considerations.

That said, here are the *small* performance considerations:

`INSERT` checks for uniqueness before acknowledging the insert.  This slows down the response time (a little) for `INSERTs`.  A plain `INDEX` is delayed and does not actually get performed until later.  See "Change buffering".  This speeds up non-unique index maintenance (a little).

A `SELECT`, when using a non-unique index will (unless something else stops it), will read rows until the value is different.  With a `UNIQUE` index, it knows to stop after one row is found.  (Again, a minor performance difference.)